# How to copy, paste and flip horizontally and vertically many images?

Tags: linux, netpbm

Basically, I have 500+ images which I need to modify in exactly the same way. I have images like this [image: Image input].

And I need to copy the left side of the image, more precisely the rectangle which dimensions are 645x999 pixels, paste it, flip it diagonally and move it on the right side. I could do this manually with any image editor but I want to know if I can make a program (preferably in c++), or enter a command that can do this for me. I wish to obtain this [image: Image output], any advice would be of great help.

Thank you.

Comment: Starting with the low-hanging fruit: Use an existing tool. https://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Basic_Batch/

Comment: Not sure why this is tagged `gnuplot`; this is probably best done in [ImageMagick](https://www.imagemagick.org).

Comment: I apologize, I removed the tag, I had no real reason to put gnuplot as a tag besides the fact that i made the images with it.

Comment: Juan David I think the idea of stackexchange is that when someone provides a helpful answer the question poster provides some sort of feedback? Maybe I got that wrong, but it seems like it would not work otherwise?

Comment: Yes, I know, the thing is I haven't had that much time to see if Gimp or ImageMagick were my solutions so I coundn't reply yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following netpbm commands show how to do this for a single file

```
cat cwxAr.png | pngtopnm | pamcut -width 670 -height 999 | pnmtopng > il.png
cat il.png | pngtopnm | pnmflip -tb | pnmflip -lr | pnmtopng > ir.png
cat il.png | pngtopnm > il.pnm
cat ir.png | pngtopnm > ir.pnm
pnmcat -lr il.pnm ir.pnm | pnmtopng > i.png
```

note - to obtain the output image that is given in the example the width is 670 pixels, not 645.

This should generate intermediate images
il.png
[image]

ir.png
[image]

and a final picture i.png

[image]

To do this for a series of files the following script would work, where the variable flist is set to the list of files to be processed

```
#!/bin/bash -f

flist=( cwxAr-0 cwxAr-1 cwxAr-2 )
outpref=( cwxAr-out )
nout=0
for f in ${flist[*]} ; do
 fout=`printf "%s-%4.4d.png" ${outpref} ${nout}`
 echo "Reading "${f}", writing ",${fout}
 cat ${f}.png   | pngtopnm | pamcut -width 670 -height 999 | pnmtopng > il.png
 cat il.png | pngtopnm | pnmflip -tb | pnmflip -lr | pnmtopng > ir.png
 cat ir.png | pngtopnm > ir.pnm
 cat il.png | pngtopnm > il.pnm
 pnmcat -lr il.pnm ir.pnm | pnmtopng > ${fout}
 nout=$(( nout +1 ))
done
```

Comment: How would I need to modify this command so I can modify a lot of images with names like 0.png, 1.png, 2.png...?

Comment: I tried this with an image and there seems to be an invalid output, is there something I must do besides change the file input?

Comment: I updated the description to make sure all intermediate files are .png and not pnm (which may have caused problem depending on viewer). I also added an example bash script to loop over a list of files and generate outputs.

Comment: This worked, perfectly. I very much appreciate your help.